# How to protect internal routes from external use in Krakend?

Tags: api-gateway, krakend

The problem is that there are too many requests due to the fact that we have to use internal authorization between microservices.

There is very little information about Krakend and there are no articles about the experience of using Krakend. Reading the documentation didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your questions correctly, you're trying to protect some "internal" routes intended to be consumed just from your microservices from external usage. Here's how you could do it with KrakenD:

**Using Separate Gateways**: The simplest approach would be to have separate gateways for external and internal requests. The external routes could be open to the outside, while the internal ones would be behind a firewall or in a private network, accessible only from your microservices.

**Adding some validation to internal resources**: If you prefer to have a single gateway for both external and internal requests, you could add protection to internal routes/endpoints. This could be achieved through authentication or header validation implemented with Common Expression Language (CEL), Security Policies, or LUA scripting.

- *CEL*: KrakenD supports CEL for defining complex matching rules for your endpoints. You can find more about it here: https://www.krakend.io/docs/endpoints/common-expression-language-cel/
- *Security Policies*: KrakenD's Security Policies Engine allows you to write custom rules that are validated at runtime during requests, responses, and token validation. This can be used to implement various validations and user access control strategies, from parameter compliance to Role-Based Access Control (RBAC) and Attribute-Based Access Control (ABAC) strategies. You can find more about it here: https://www.krakend.io/docs/enterprise/security-policies/
- *LUA*: KrakenD also supports LUA scripting for endpoint logic. You can find more about it here: https://www.krakend.io/docs/endpoints/lua/

**Filtering origin IPs**: Another way to protect access to some routes for internal usage is by using the IP filter component. This allows you to define which IPs can access certain endpoints. You can find more about it here: https://www.krakend.io/docs/enterprise/throttling/ipfilter/

I hope this helps!